# Circle with arrow symbol interpretation in circuit

Tags: current, parallel, ohms-law

I am trying to find all currents in this circuit:

[image]

(Question 19 from https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/worksheets/algebraic-equation-manipulation-for-electric-circuits/)

Although I'm familiar with Ohm's law and can find values in series-parallel circuits, I don't know how to approach this.

What is the meaning of the circle with arrow in it symbol, that has 5mA?

Should I interpret that as an extra power source? Why not use a battery symbol there then?

What is the approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Arrow sources are high impedance current regulated , in this case constant DC mA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *What is the meaning of the circle with arrow in it symbol, that has
> 5mA?*

It's a constant current source - it draws a constant 5 mA come what may.

> *Should I interpret that as an extra power source?*

You should interpret that as a current source - it can be converted to a voltage source in series with a resistor if that might help you - look up Thevenin equivalent sources: -

[image]